# Setting default value of text box in template, based on other control in the page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a detail view and I'd like one of the fields to have default value taken from different label, which is in turn taken from previous page.

The code of the view is:

```
 <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="gkey" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceEmployees" Height="50px" Width="125px" OnLoad="DetailsView1_Load">
                <Fields>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="gkey" HeaderText="gkey" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="gkey" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Department" SortExpression="Department">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Department") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Department") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Department") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SIP" HeaderText="SIP" SortExpression="SIP" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="color" HeaderText="color" SortExpression="color" />
                    <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="on_call" HeaderText="on_call" SortExpression="on_call" />
                    <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="on_leave" HeaderText="on_leave" SortExpression="on_leave" />
                    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ShowInsertButton="True" />
                </Fields>
            </asp:DetailsView>
```

Now I am trying to set the value of TextBox1

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


                ((TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox1")).Text = LabelSelectedDepartament.Text;



}
```

But that gives me a NullReferenceException. I've tried to put the same line to DetailsVie1_load, but that gives the same error. What am I missing?

EDIT: I am transferring data from previous page correctly, I've just skipped that part since its irrelevant, but since you insist:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Page previousPage = Page.PreviousPage;
    if (previousPage != null)
    {

        Label tst = FindControlRecursive(previousPage, "lblDepartment") as Label;
        LabelSelectedDepartament.Text = tst.Text;

        //And here is error
       ((TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox1")).Text = LabelSelectedDepartament.Text;

    }


}

//This fantastic procedure below allows to find controls within controls (i.e. label inside the table)

private Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
{
    if (root.ID == id)
    {
        return root;
    }
    foreach (Control c in root.Controls)
    {
        Control t = FindControlRecursive(c, id);
        if (t != null)
        {
            return t;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Edit2: I am not trying to look for the value in the PreviousPage, it is already on current page (and its displaying properly), so all I need is something like

```
TextBox1.Text=LabelSelectedDepartament.Text
```

Edit3

I've tried to put `((TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox1")).Text = LabelSelectedDepartament.Text;` into

- DetailsView1_DataBound
- Mode_changed
- ItemsInserting

I think I am addressing it somehow wrong.

Comment: uhh, I am transferring value properly, I've omitted it from the code because it was irrelevant

Comment: You have multiple controls with ID=TextBox1.

Comment: Strangely, that is generated by wizard (above its the out-of-the-box details view with template), because they don't exist at the same time. changing their names don't fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can access the TextBox1 in DataBound event of DetailsView. Before the databound there is nothing to find in that control.

Comment: I was expecting that, but unfortunately I still get NullReferenceException - object reference not set to an instance of an object. I believe it has to be other event, since on DataBound the TexBox1 doesn't exist (it shows up on edit only)